# how to dismiss bootstrap popover when either click again or click elsewhere

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I can use `data-trigger='focus'` to dismiss a popover when click outside, or `data-trigger='click'` when click the button again. But I can't have BOTH. That is, if I use `focus`, clicking the popover button won't do anything.

I'd like to dismiss popover in either case, does anyone know a way to do this easily?

I tried `data-trigger='focus click'`, but it doesn't work.

EDIT: I don't think this is a duplicated question. Sure the solution in that question work for me. But the title of that question: **"How to dismiss a Twitter Bootstrap popover by clicking outside"** is misleading. If I just want dismiss the popover by clicking outside, I just need `data-trigger='focus'`, as said by bootstrap document:

> Use the focus trigger to dismiss popovers on the next click that the user makes.

But as I explained, it won't work if you click the popover trigger again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not to sure what you mean without seeing any code but I would do it using jQuery:

```
    $('body').on('click', function (e) {

    if ($(e.target).data('toggle') !== 'popover'
        && $(e.target).parents('.popover.in').length === 0) { 
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('hide');
    }
});
```

I hope I was of some help, good luck!